# Magento date format issue in Arabic store on customer account page

Tags: magento, locale, date-format

On customer account page /customer/account/

in English store view date is coming in correct format like 7/11/2013

but when i switch to arabic store view its displaying in wrong format like 72013/11/

It is calling this function:

```
$this->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAtStoreDate())
```

Answer (score 1):

After searching a lot i found a solution...

In this file

```
  lib\Zend\Locale\Data\ar.xml
```

there is tag

```
  <dateFormats>
    ....
   <dateFormatLength type="short">
    <dateFormat>
        <pattern>d‏/M‏/yyyy</pattern>
    </dateFormat>
</dateFormatLength>
```

It had some spaces in pattern tag so i removed those spaces.. and bingo!! it worked!!